# "+1 Overload --- Function definition for '...' not found" Along With "Unable to start program. The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, function

This code is written for homework where I am prompting user input to calculate hospital bills based on whether the patient was admitted as an inpatient or an outpatient, along with user-inputted rates and charges. The issue I am having is that when I try to run the code, the system first tells me that there are build errors and asks if I would like to continue. After continuing, I get the following error message:

"Unable to start program.
[File Path]
The system cannot find the specified file"

I was going through my code and the only thing I could see was that the function prototypes before the main function had a message stating that the function definition could not be found.

Are there issues with my code or is this purely an issue with Visual Studio 2017? My directory doesn't look out of order or anything like that.

```
// PGM6 - Overloaded Hospital - 11.15.2020

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double inpatient(int days, double rateDaily, double chargesService, double chargesMeds, double chargesTotal);
double outpatient(double chargesService, double chargesMeds, double chargesTotal);

int main()
{
    int patientType;

    cout << "Please enter (1) for Inpatient or (2) for Outpatient" << endl;
    cin >> patientType;

    if (patientType == 1)
        double inpatient();
    else 
        if (patientType == 2)
            double outpatient();
        else
            cout << "Please enter (1) or (2)." << endl;
}

double inpatient()
{
    int days;
    double rate;
    double chargesService;
    double chargesMeds;
    double chargesTotal = (days * rate) + chargesService + chargesMeds;

    cout << "Days: ";
    cin >> days;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Daily Rate: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Service Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesService;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Medication Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesMeds;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Total Charges: " << chargesTotal << endl;

    return chargesTotal;

}

double outpatient()
{
    double chargesService;
    double chargesMeds;
    double chargesTotal = chargesService + chargesMeds;

    cout << "Service Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesService;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Medication Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesMeds;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Total Charges: " << chargesTotal << endl;

    return chargesTotal;
}
```

Comment: If there are build errors then look at those. Choosing to continue doesn’t make sense as there is no executable to run.

Comment: At the beginning of your code, you give a declaration of `inpatient` that takes 5 arguments. You call it with 0 arguments, and later you give a definition that takes 0. How is the function supposed to work? ETA: Sorry, you _don't_ call it with 0 arguments, you declare a new overload of it that takes 0 arguments and then don't do anything with it.

Comment: The declarations and the defintions of `inpatient` and `outpatient` don't match. You must fix them first.

Comment: Aside from the issues with the function declarations with no matching definitions and the fact that your `main` code is declaring, not invoking, `double inpatient();` and `double outpatient();`, the actual definitions of those functions all act on uninitialized variables. `double chargesTotal = chargesService + chargesMeds;` performs the computation with whatever is in `chargesService` and `chargesMeds` when the statement is executed; it doesn't retroactively go back in after you've initialized them and calculate a new value for `chargesTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you did wrong

1. The prototypes of your functions didn't need parameters as the values are typed by the user within the function.
2. When you call outpatient and inpatient, just type the name of the function with the parenthesis (don't type double in front, that's a new declaration).
3. chargesTotal had to be initialized just before printing it (after asking the needed values to the user)

I think this working code do what you need :

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double inpatient();
double outpatient();

int main()
{
    int patientType;

    cout << "Please enter (1) for Inpatient or (2) for Outpatient" << endl;
    cin >> patientType;

    if(patientType == 1)
    inpatient();
    else if(patientType == 2)
    outpatient();
    else
    cout << "Please enter (1) or (2)." << endl;
}

double inpatient()
{
    int days;
    double rate;
    double chargesService;
    double chargesMeds;

    cout << "Days: ";
    cin >> days;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Daily Rate: ";
    cin >> rate;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Service Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesService;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Medication Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesMeds;
    cout << endl << endl;

    double chargesTotal = (days * rate) + chargesService + chargesMeds;

    cout << "Total Charges: " << chargesTotal << endl;

    return chargesTotal;
}

double outpatient()
{
    double chargesService;
    double chargesMeds;

    cout << "Service Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesService;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Medication Charges: ";
    cin >> chargesMeds;
    cout << endl << endl;

    double chargesTotal = chargesService + chargesMeds;
    cout << "Total Charges: " << chargesTotal << endl;

    return chargesTotal;
}
```

Comment: chargesTotal can of course be declared with the other variables (at the beginning of the function) but must be initialized just before being used when the needed values were already completed by the user

Comment: I forgot to mention that my professor wants us to use overloaded functions in this, does that change anything? Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Actually, no. But as we didn't have the file 'pch.h' I didn't include it. Are there some inpatient()/outpatient() declarations in it? So you understand (because it's the more important -> to understand what you do) a function overload is simply declaring two time a function with the same names but with different arguments. example : ```double outpatient();``` and ```double outpatient(int aVariable);```The second declaration is an overload of the first one.